# Identity and Inverse Homomorphisms

Tags: abelian-groups, abstract-algebra

For a group G and an abelian group H, Hom(G,H) is the set of all homomorphisms from G to H. My notes from class talk about the identity and the inverse homomorphism- I was wondering what these are?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $G$ is a group and $H$ is an (additive) abelian group, $\hom_{\text{grp}} (G,H)$ forms an (additive) abelian group with pointwise addition: $(f_1+f_2)(g)=f_1(g)+f_2(g)$, for $f_1,f_2\in \hom (G,H)$ and $g\in G$.  You should check that the sum of two homomorphisms is a homomorphism.  The identity in this group is the zero homomorphism, while the inverse of a homomorphism is given by $(-f)(g)=-f(g)$, where $f\in \hom (G,H)$ and $g\in G$.

Comment: What is pointwise addition?

Comment: I see. Thanks for your help Seth.

Answer (score 1):

The identity map $1_G:G \rightarrow G$ on a set is the function which sends each element to itself.

You should verify that this is a homomorphism, and that when a homomorphism is a bijection, the inverse function is also a homomorphism.

Comment: I see... Is there only an inverse homomorphism when the homomorphism is a bijection? Does this mean f: G->H is a bijective homomorphism (isomorphism) and f^-1 is also an isomorphism?

Comment: I do not believe that this is what the OP's notes are referring to.  I think my answer has the correct interpretation.

Comment: @Seth They did not supply enough information to determine that.

Comment: @LokiClock i agree that there isn't enough information.  I went with my interpretation because it relates to hom(G,H).

Comment: @JC1397 You could ask if $G$ induces a group structure on its power set, and then ask if that shows the inverse image function sending each point in $H$ to its inverse image is a homomorphism. But this is not what people mean by the inverse homomorphism.

Comment: @JC1397 You should verify which terminology is being used before you continue. You often see the terms *additive inverse* and the *zero homomorphism* used precisely because of the multiple meanings, but you can't count on people choosing clarity over convenience.

Comment: @LokiClock Sorry about that, I'm just going off what I have in my notes. I think we aren't at an advanced enough part of the class to properly differentiate between all the terms. The trivial/zero homomorphism is just the homomorphism that maps every element to the unit element, right? Thanks.

Comment: @JC1397 It is indeed. You can phrase that without reference to elements by showing there's a unique homomorphism between any two groups which factors through the trivial group.

Comment: I see, thanks @LokiClock.

Answer (score 1):

If $(H,+)$ is an abelian group, then $Hom (G,H)$ can be given a group structure. Infact, given two homomorphisms $f,g: G \longrightarrow H$ we can define their sum
$f+g : G \longrightarrow H$ componentwise with the formula
$$(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$$

The identity of $Hom (G,H)$ is just the $0$ homomorphism, and the inverse of $f$ is just defined by $(-f)(x) = -(f(x))$.